# Blender file view scripts default path

Tags: scripting

How can I set blender scripts file view path in python so it would automatically open specific folder? Currently it opens the folder where .blend file is.

script currently:

````
import bpy  


def write_some_data(context, filepath, use_some_setting):
    print("running write_some_data...")
    
    scene = bpy.context.scene  
    frame = scene.frame_start
    cube = bpy.data.objects['Tracker1']
    f = open(filepath, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    while frame <= scene.frame_end:
        scene.frame_set(frame) 
        x, y, z = cube.location
        x_pixels = x * (256 / 15)
        y_pixels = y * (256 / 15)
        f.write("%d" % frame)
        f.write("\n")
        f.write("%5.3f" % (x_pixels))
        f.write("\n")
        f.write("%5.3f" % (y_pixels))
        f.write("\n")
        frame += 1 
    f.close()  

    return {'FINISHED'}


# ExportHelper is a helper class, defines filename and
# invoke() function which calls the file selector.
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty, EnumProperty
from bpy.types import Operator

 
class ExportSomeData(Operator, ExportHelper):
    """This appears in the tooltip of the operator and in the generated docs"""
    bl_idname = "export_test.some_data"  # important since its how bpy.ops.import_test.some_data is constructed
    bl_label = "Export Some Data"

    # ExportHelper mixin class uses this 
    filename_ext = ".txt"
    

    filter_glob: StringProperty(
        default="*.txt",
        options={'HIDDEN'},
        maxlen=255,  # Max internal buffer length, longer would be clamped.
    )

    # List of operator properties, the attributes will be assigned
    # to the class instance from the operator settings before calling.
    use_setting: BoolProperty(
        name="Example Boolean",
        description="Example Tooltip",
        default=True,
    )

    type: EnumProperty(
        name="Example Enum",
        description="Choose between two items",
        items=(
            ('OPT_A', "First Option", "Description one"),
            ('OPT_B', "Second Option", "Description two"),
        ),
        default='OPT_A',
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        return write_some_data(context, self.filepath, self.use_setting)


# Only needed if you want to add into a dynamic menu
def menu_func_export(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ExportSomeData.bl_idname, text="Text Export Operator")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ExportSomeData)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.append(menu_func_export)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ExportSomeData)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func_export)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.export_test.some_data('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```
````

Comment: `bpy.ops.export_test.some_data('INVOKE_DEFAULT', filepath="path")`, `self.layout.operator(ExportSomeData.bl_idname, text="Text Export Operator").filepath="path"`

Comment: ´Thanks for answer, where do I put that?

Comment: You need to add the `filepath=` parts. First line of Jay's comment is the last line in your script (line 90, test call), and the second one is line 74 (below `def menu_func_export(self, context):`) where the dynamic menu entry is created (*File > Export > Text Export Operator*). Make sure the path ends with a '/, for example `"/tmp/"`